# JQuery datepicker jump ahead by years insted of months

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The default Jquery UI datepicker allows the calendar to have a single arrow, and jump ahead by a month. Is there any way to add in a feature to make it jump up by years too? Like maybe a double arrow?

The only option I see is this:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: Is this question still open? Please let us know your findings, or how else we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only datepicker alternatives that I know of are:

[Anytime](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)
[Kevin Luck's datepicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/)

Fortunately, Kevin Luck's plugin will do the trick for you.  [See this demo](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiMonthPopup.html).